# The wicked female monster!

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

According to Online Etymology Dictionary, the "mare" in [night**mare**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=nightmare&searchmode=none) means  an evil female spirit/monster that affects sleepers during the night.

Very interesting. Are there other words in English referring to female monsters or evil spirits, which mean a different thing? I'm very curious to find out.

Comment: _mother-in-law_. [1](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0369735/)

Comment: It's not female, but _puck_ ("evil spirit" or "sprite") is thought to be the source of _pug_. (http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pug&allowed_in_frame=0_)

Comment: sure... harpie, siren, gorgon... and some non-monster words but still along the same lines, like hag...

Answer (score 1):

A *succubus* is a female demon, derived from medieval latin *succuba* strumpet. *Incubus* is a similar term, either masculine or non-specific, depending on where you get your information. But that is the problem with such a question; it is not hard to find a grimoire (mediaeval, pseudo-mediaeval, Wiccan, or role-playing game) that will tell you which evil spirits are feminine, but it is extremely hard to find two sources that agree on the taxonomy.